# Sample space of drawing 3 balls from a bag of 6 black balls and 5 while balls.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If 3 balls are randomly drawn from an urn containing 6 white and 5 black balls, what is
the probability that one of the drawn balls is white and the other two black?

1) What is the sample space for this problem?

i.e is it $\{\{w,w,w\},\{b,w,w\},\{b,b,w\},\{b,b,b\}\}$ where ordering does not count 
or

$\{\{w,w,w\},\{w,w,b\},\{w,b,w\},\{b,w,w\},\{b,b,w\},\{b,w,b\},\{w,b,b\},\{b,b,b\}\}$ where ordering does count.

The solution to the problem counts the number of elements in the sample space as ${11 \choose 3}$ and gives the correct answer eventually as $\frac{4}{11}$.

Can anyone explain what is happening?

Comment: I'm not sure what the notation in  the answer you propose means.  I think, though, that you are incorrectly assuming that all the elements in your "sample space" have the same probability.  They do not.

Comment: The sample space is simply ${11\choose 3}$

Comment: why is that? ${11 \choose 3}$ would include {w,w,w} multiple times wouldn't it

Comment: Because the sample space is the space of ALL possible outcomes for drawing three balls. You then find the event space and divide the two for the probability.

Comment: For intuition, it's best to imagine that the balls were numbered.  $w_1,w_2,\cdots, b_1,b_2$.  Then, sure you get $(w,w,w)$ multiple times depending on which white balls you draw.

Comment: oh the sample space is then a multiset?

Comment: Yes, it's one outcome counted multiple times.  The advantage of doing it this way is that each "instance" now has the same probability.

Comment: @Jhon Doe Each white ball is different. You get the same set of white balls only once.

Comment: I think it's clearer to think of it the way I said...with numbered balls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample space can be chosen to be multiple things; both the choices you said would work. However, the most convenient choices are the ones where all the elements of the sample space are equally likely. In this problem, there are $11$ equally likely possibilities for the first ball, and then $10$ equally likely possibilities for the next, and then $9$ for the last, suggesting that a good sample space would consist of all $11\cdot 10\cdot 9$ ordered selections of balls. However, since order does not matter, it is also okay to group the sample space into groups of $3!=6$ corresponding to the six orderings of each unordered selection. Still, every unordered outcome is equally likely.

Note that even though the while balls are indistinguishable, they behave as distinguishable balls when calculating the probability of events.